# How can I draw a square at a specific position with p5 shader?

Tags: shader, p5.js, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

Using p5.js I have :

```js
s.draw = () => {
    s.background(0);
    s.translate(-s.windowWidth / 2, -s.windowHeight / 2, 0);
    s.shader(shader);
    shader.setUniform("u_resolution", [s.width, s.height]);
    shader.setUniform('vPos', getSquarePoints(cols/2, rows/2));
    s.square(0, 0, cellSize);    
}

const getSquarePoints = (i, j) => {
        return new Float32Array([
            i, j,
            (i + cellSize), j,
            i, (j + cellSize),
            (i + cellSize), j,
            (i + cellSize), (j + cellSize),
            i, (j + cellSize),
        ])
    }
```

My vertex :

```c
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

attribute vec3 aPosition;

varying vec2 vPos;

void main() {
    vec4 positionVec4 = vec4(aPosition, 1.0);

    positionVec4.xy = positionVec4.xy * 2.0 - 1.0;

    gl_Position = positionVec4;
}
```

The fragment :

```c
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

uniform vec2 u_resolution;

varying vec2 vPos;

void main() {

    vec2 st = gl_FragCoord.xy / u_resolution.xy;

    gl_FragColor = vec4(st.x, st.y, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

So the vPos has the wrong type, but my plan was to define the 6 points needed to make a square with 2 triangles and send those points to the position buffer.

- How can I do that ?
- Is this even the "right way" to proceed ?

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand this enough to give proper feedback, but as no one more clever has answered I'll try. I did get something similar working using the process below:

1, create an image object in your draw function:

```
let pixel_image = createImage(width, height);
pixel_image.loadPixels();
```

2, fill the pixels of the image using .set(), i and j, should come from a loop and be the pixels you want to overwrite.

```
pixel_image.set(i, j, color(0, 90, 102));
```

3, update the image pixels

```
pixel_image.updatePixels();
```

[Check out create image in p5.js from pixel locations on how to do these steps above fully](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createImage)

4, save the image to a variable to be picked up in the shader.frag file. i called the variable pixel_coords for some reason:

```
shader.setUniform('pixel_coords', pixel_image);
```

5, in the shader.frag file you will see the image being passed in:
uniform sampler2D pixel_coords;

[check this out for the shader files image from p5 to shaders for more insight](https://github.com/aferriss/p5jsShaderExamples/tree/gh-pages/3_uniforms/3-2_texture2d)

Shader frag file:

```
precision mediump float;
// we need our texcoords for drawing textures
varying vec2 vTexCoord;
// images are sent to the shader as a variable type called sampler2D
uniform sampler2D pixel_coords;
void main() {
  // by default, our texcoords will be upside down
  // lets flip them by inverting the y component
  vec2 uv = vTexCoord;
  uv.y = 1.0 - uv.y;
  // we can access our image by using the GLSL shader function texture2D()
  // texture2D expects a sampler2D, and texture coordinates as it's input
  vec4 image = texture2D(pixel_coords, uv);
  gl_FragColor = image;
}
```

shader vert file

```
// our vertex data
attribute vec3 aPosition;
// our texcoordinates
attribute vec2 aTexCoord;
// this is a variable that will be shared with the fragment shader
// we will assign the attribute texcoords to the varying texcoords to move them from the vert shader to the frag shader
// it can be called whatever you want but often people prefix it with 'v' to indicate that it is a varying
varying vec2 vTexCoord;
void main() {
  // copy the texture coordinates
  vTexCoord = aTexCoord;
  // copy the position data into a vec4, using 1.0 as the w component
  vec4 positionVec4 = vec4(aPosition, 1.0);
  positionVec4.xy = positionVec4.xy * 2.0 - 1.0;
  // send the vertex information on to the fragment shader
  gl_Position = positionVec4;
}
```